# Highcharts - Trying to get a dyamic spline to update from left to right

Tags: dynamic, highcharts, spline

Thought this would be simple enough but am having not much luck finding a reference to this in the Highchart API.

I would like to have the dynamic line chart display the xAxis updates from left to right. i.e., the tadpole swimming to the left margin.
Can't for the life of me find a parameter to do this.

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

Answer (score 0):

Well.... should have seen that.

```
 xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 100,
        reversed:true,
    },
```